# MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out with NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am attempting to connect to a Mongo database running on a VPS with NodeJS and Express. Here is my code:

```
const app = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

const connectionString = "mongodb://[Username]:[Password]@[IP Address]:[Port Number]/[Database]"

MongoClient.connect(connectionString, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err)
  console.log('Connected to Database')
})

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on 3000')
})
```

I am expecting it to print 'Connected to Database' but instead it throws the following exception:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/[user]/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map { '[IP Adress]:[Port Number]' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

I am able to succesfully access the IP address on my browser. It leads me to the default index page for an Apache webserver.
Running `show users` inside the `mongo` terminal after selecting my database gives the following response:

```
{
    "_id" : "[Database].[Username]",
    "userId" : UUID("1545d0ec-1309-4e40-82e4-7777afb266fe"),
    "user" : [Username],
    "db" : [Database],
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : [Database]
        }
    ],
    "mechanisms" : [
        "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
    ]
}
```

What would be the appropriate steps to continue debugging this? Is there any more information I should provide?

Answer (score 2):

- Go to [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) and Sign in;
- Check your Network access;
- If your IP access list is empty, add a new IP access, otherwise,
  delete the current IP and add a new ip. [Choose your current IP
  address].

This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Check your connection string, make sure it is properly constructed. It could be missing something, or is using the wrong protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing it in as an async function, and then try and catch it.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const connectionString = "mongodb://[Username]:[Password]@[IP Address]:[Port Number]/[Database]"

const connect = async () => {
    try {
        const client = await mongodb.connect(connectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true });
        console.log('connected to mongodb');
        return client;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```